# Choosing from multiple network connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista, ethernet

I have two different ISPs in my home and also two different routers. I'm using one for Wireless, and one for ethernet.

On my PC here, it has both wireless and ethernet connections setup at the same time (which is what I want). But I want to use my wireless connection for connecting to the internet. However, it seems like the internet connection is getting prioritized to my hardwired ethernet connection instead.

Is there anyway to change this without disabling the ethernet connection? I need both of them enabled.

I'm using Windows Vista.

Comment: can i ask WHY would you be paying for 2 separate services with all the networking tech out there right now? smh

Comment: It has to do with my business. It's not that big of a deal. ISPs usually only charge like $50 per month each.

Comment: if it has to do with expenses, i run my company from home, and deduct my home internet as an expense.

Comment: Also this question doesn't make any sense whats so ever, why you require the wireless over the wired wasn't stated and is important information. Wired > Wireless any day of the year. I'm assuming it has something to do with networking files or printers, Which is why you should have 1 connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Interface metric to override which default gateway is used.

You can go to your Wired Network adapter properties via Control Panel / Network and Internet / Network Connections.

In the network adapter properties window, double-click Internet Protocol Version 4, and then click on Advanced button.

Uncheck Automatic metric button, and put 100 to the Interface metric box. Then click OK to exit the adapter properties windows.

After this, your wireless interface has a default metric of 10, and wired interface has a metric of 100.

Interface metric is the cost of sending a packet through the interface. Since the cost of wired interface is now higher, packets are sent via the wireless interface.

Answer (score 0):

The **fastest way** is to **disable (remove) the gateway** in one of your network adapters, so it will loose internet, but not LAN.
Assuming your wired device is at `192.168.1.x` subnet, and `192.168.1.1` as its gateway/router, this command-line removes the gateway:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

To enable (add) gateway again:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

This change will last until the next reboot. If you want to automate it in a simple script, so you can run it whenever desired, I suggest [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/710954/fastest-way-to-disable-internet-keeping-lan-from-command-line).
If you want to make this change permanent, I suggest you to edit TCP/IP properties *for that ethernet adapte* directly at (my Windows is in Spanish, sorry):
[image: Disabling Gateway at TCP/IP Properties]
(This image assumes `192.168.1.20` for your LAN IP Address. DNSs are just an example)