# Disable default gateway on router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, gateway

I have a router that I'm connecting to a laptop through ethernet, this router is acting as an access point for other devices. At the same time I'm connecting to the internet through wifi. I achieved this by going into TCP/IP settings in windows and setting a static IP for the LAN ethernet interface and not specifying a default gateway, that way it will use wifi to access the internet.

This works, but I'm wondering if there's another way besides setting the static IP and not specifying a gateway deep within windows settings. Is it possible to do from the router maybe?

Comment: Please (exactly!) name make and model of your router.

Comment: Its still buried deep in the network settings, but the interface metric is the setting you really want to modify. (http://superuser.com/a/740347/820)  Also see this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564).

Comment: The router is a TP-Link TL-WR702N Nano Router. And I'm looking for a way to do this through the router, metric settings won't help here.