# Batch file for configuring the ip address and removing it

Tags: networking, ip, batch-file, window

My pc has a network configuration 
IP- 192.168.0.99
    192.168.4.20
Mask- 255.255.255.0
      255.255.255.0
Gateway- 192.168.0.1
         192.168.4.1

I am connecting to the internet through the gateway 192.168.4.1. I want to disable the internet sometimes, so i need to remove the gateway 192.168.4.1, How can I achieve this through a batch file... I have created a batch file to add ip address to the interface.

```
netsh int ip set address "LAN" static 192.168.0.99 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 
netsh int ip add address "LAN" static 192.168.4.20 255.255.255.0 192.168.4.1
interface ip set dns "LAN" static 192.168.0.1
interface ip add dns "LAN" static 8.8.8.8
```

but this gives errors.If I use 'set' instead of ip 'add' in the second line, 192.168.0.99 is overwritten by 192.168.4.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows command-line: Fastest way to disable internet (keeping LAN)?](http://superuser.com/questions/744526/windows-command-line-fastest-way-to-disable-internet-keeping-lan)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable Internet access while keeping local network access, you could just edit your routing table and remove your default route:

Within an elevate command prompt, these two commands should delete and recreate your default route:

- route DELETE 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0
- route ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.4.1

Note that the first command is temporary. Windows can recreate the default route after restarting the interface (or PC)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing "set" to "add" where both are "add"

netsh int ip set address "LAN" static 192.168.0.99 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
netsh int ip add address "LAN" static 192.168.4.20 255.255.255.0 192.168.4.1